# For each element in an array, if the element is less than its previous element, increase it till the previous element with one

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

Suppose I have an array: list1 = [8, 5, 3, 1, 1, 10, 15, 9]
Now if the element is less than its previous element, increase it till the previous element with one.

Here:

> 5 < 8 so 5 should become: 5 + 3 + 1 = 9 i.e (8+1)
>
> 3 < 5 so 3 should become: 3 + 2 + 1 = 6 i.e (5+1)
>
> 1 < 3 so 1 should become: 1 + 2 + 1 = 4 i.e (3+1)

Now I am able to get the difference between elements if its less than its previous element.
But, how to use it in a final list to get an output like this:

> finallist = [8, 9, 6, 4, 1, 10, 15, 16]

Also how can I get a final list value of 'k' list in my code? Right now it shows:

> [2] 
>   [2, 4]
>   [2, 4, 3]
>   [2, 4, 3, 3]
>   [2, 4, 3, 3, 7]

Source code:

```
list1 = [8, 5, 3, 1, 1, 10, 15, 9]

k = []

def comput(x):
    if i[x] < i[x-1]:
        num = (i[x-1] - i[x]) + 1
        k.append(num)
        print(k)
    return


for i in [list1]:
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        comput(j)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will create a new list with the required output

```
l1 = [8, 5, 3, 1, 1, 10, 15, 9]
l = [l1[0]]
c=[0]         # cost / difference list

for i in range(len(l1)-1):
    if l1[i+1] < l1[i]:
        l.append(l1[i]+1)
        c.append(l1[i]+1-l1[i+1])
    else:
        l.append(l1[i+1])
        c.append(0)
print(l)
```

Output

```
[8, 9, 6, 4, 1, 10, 15, 16]
[0, 4, 3, 3, 0,  0,  0,  7]
```

Comment: This is the final list. I also want the cost of increment too. Like 5 got incremented by 4. 3 got incremented by 3.

Comment: So, how to get that increment values? I got  [2, 4, 3, 3, 7] which is correct. How to get it here? Or even better: Can we get a cost list like: [0, 4,3,3,0,0,0,7,2] ?

Comment: @TarakShah updated! used a separate list `c` for differences.

Comment: Just curious! If I wanted to make increment to my finallist how would I do it? Here final list we got is [8, 9, 6, 4, 1, 10, 15, 16] so applying same logic, can we make final list as [8, 9, 10, 11,12, 13,15,16] ??

Comment: simply you can change `l1` to `[8, 9, 6, 4, 1, 10, 15, 16]`. If you want to do this operation twice on the initial `l1` then, define a function and run it twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension for this.  Basically, the following code will check if one is larger than the next.  If it is, then it will convert it to the previous+1.

```
list1 = [8, 5, 3, 1, 1, 10, 15, 9]

k = [list1[0]] + [i if j<=i else j+1 for i,j in zip(list1[1:],list1[:-1])]
cost = [j-i for i,j in zip(list1,k)]
print(k)
print(cost)
```

Output:

```
[8, 9, 6, 4, 1, 10, 15, 16]
[0, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7]
```

Comment: This is the final list. I also want the cost of increment too. Like 5 got incremented by 4. 3 got incremented by 3. So, how to get that increment values? I got [2, 4, 3, 3, 7] which is correct. How to get it here? Or even better: Can we get a cost list like: [0, 4,3,3,0,0,0,7,] ?

Comment: Man I just got i :D

Comment: @Tarak I updated my answer.  If I helped you, if you could mark as solution / upvote, it would help a lot.

Comment: Just curious! If I wanted to make increment to my finallist how would I do it? Here final list we got is  [8, 9, 6, 4, 1, 10, 15, 16] so applying same logic, can we make final list as [8, 9, 10, 11,12, 13,15,16] ??